# making two tier div table with 2D array doesnt work properly

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have an array like so  :

```
TestingTable : [
       {TestingType:[
             {Id:1,Name:"Functional Testing"},
             {Id:2,Name:"Regression Testing"},
             {Id:3,Name:"Integration"},
             {Id:4,Name:"BVT"}]
       },
      {EnvironmentTypes:[
             {Id:1,Name:"Dev/QE (VCD)"},
             {Id:2,Name:"Staging"},
             {Id:3,Name:"PPE"},
             {Id:4,Name:"01's"}]
      }
]
```

I want to use the above array and create a div table like this :

[image]

So far ive tried it this way but its not coming the way i want it to ..

```
<h3>Testing</h3>
<div class="rTable" ng-if="show" ng-repeat="item in TestingTable">
    <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableHead"><strong></strong>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableHead" ng-repeat="test in item.EnvironmentTypes"><span style="font-weight: bold;">{{test.Name}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rTableRow" ng-repeat="environ in item.TestingType">
        <div class="rTableHead"><span style="font-weight: bold;">{{environ.Name}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableCell" ng-repeat="test in item.EnvironmentTypes">
            <input type="text" ng-model="result">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

How should i use the ng repeat in order to get the two tier table in the picture?

Comment: Your array describes only structure of table. Where is example of actual data for table filling?

Comment: I get that from another Array. For now i just want the table to show with the cells with the values as blank cells. could you help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.TestingTable = [
       {TestingType:[
             {Id:1,Name:"Functional Testing"},
             {Id:2,Name:"Regression Testing"},
             {Id:3,Name:"Integration"},
             {Id:4,Name:"BVT"}]
       },
      {EnvironmentTypes:[
             {Id:1,Name:"Dev/QE (VCD)"},
             {Id:2,Name:"Staging"},
             {Id:3,Name:"PPE"},
             {Id:4,Name:"01's"}]
      }
  ];
}])
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #2b91d6;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
thead tr{
    background-color:#97cff5;
    text-align:center;
}
td{
    width:130px;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="ctrl">
 <table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td ng-repeat='item in TestingTable[1].EnvironmentTypes'>{{item.Name}}</td>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat='item in TestingTable[0].TestingType'>
       <td style='text-align:right'>{{item.Name}}</td>
       <td ng-repeat='x in TestingTable[1].EnvironmentTypes'></td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

See this solution

In your template file

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th ng-repeat="item in data[1].EnvironmentTypes">{{item.Name}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in data[0].TestingType">
      <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="item1 in data[1].EnvironmentTypes"></td>

    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

In your controller

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data =  [
       {TestingType:[
             {Id:1,Name:"Functional Testing"},
             {Id:2,Name:"Regression Testing"},
             {Id:3,Name:"Integration"},
             {Id:4,Name:"BVT"}]
       },
      {EnvironmentTypes:[
             {Id:1,Name:"Dev/QE (VCD)"},
             {Id:2,Name:"Staging"},
             {Id:3,Name:"PPE"},
             {Id:4,Name:"01's"}]
      }
];

});
```

[image]

Comment: I am glad, that you fully agree with my solution.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov Accidentally. :)